# Given csv data, i want to know "What week(here week means dd in date) of the year in 2018 had the most fire calls"?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

**My question is i tried solving the query using this sql statement**

```
select to_char(CallDate,"dd") week ,count(to_char(CallDate,"dd")) as count from demo_db.fire_service_calls_tbl where to_char(CallDate,"yyyy") = "2018" group by week order by count desc
```

But instructor solved using this

```
select weekofyear(to_date(CallDate,"MM/dd/yyyy")) week_year, count(*) as count from demo_db.fire_service_calls_tbl  where year(to_date(CallDate,"yyyy")) == 2018 group by week_year order by count desc
```

**They both should ideally return same answer but my answer is different from his answer.

Where am i going wrong ?**

This is the Data frame data, you can covert this to globalview table

```
fire_df = spark.read \
                .format("csv") \
                .option("header", "true") \
                .option("inferSchema", "true") \
                .load("/databricks-datasets/learning-spark-v2/sf-fire/sf-fire-calls.csv")
```

..........................

Answer (score 1):

The `to_char(CallDate,"dd") week` in your SQL query will convert the `CallDate` to a string representing the day of the month. The `"dd"` format model returns the day of the month, from 01 to 31. The `week` is an alias for the same on which you are grouping by.

For example, if `CallDate` is `'2022-09-15'`, `to_char(CallDate,"dd")` will return `'15'`.

Whereas, in you instructor's query `weekofyear(to_date(CallDate,"MM/dd/yyyy")) week_year` will return the week of the year for a specified date. The weeks are numbered from 1 to 53. Week 1 of a year is the first week that contains at least four days in the new year.

Hence, the difference in result.

You can use the following alternatives which returns the week of the year:

1. `DATE_PART('week', CallDate) AS week`
2. `weekofyear(CallDate) AS week` (refer [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/weekofyear.html))
3. `EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CallDate) AS week`